# How do you customize a NodeJS deployment to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application written with NodeJS for the webserver and Angular on the frontend.

The structure is like this

```
musicapp
   |-- server
   |     |--- src/
   |     |--- node_modules/
   |     |--- package.json
   |--- client
         |--- src/
         |--- node_modules/
         |--- package.json
```

When I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk using `eb deploy` nothing happens, and I've realized it must be because the default action for Elastic Beanstalk is to call `npm install` and `npm start` but in my case, that doesn't do anything when called on the root.

So my question is, how do I tell Elastic Beanstalk: **upon deploy, `cd` to client and call `npm install`, `npm run build` and then `cd` to server and call `npm install`, `npm start`** ?

I can't find anything in the EB documentation that explains how one might do this.

Answer (score 4):

In your root folder create a dir called `.ebextensions` and inside that folder create a file called `01_npm.config` (for example).

In that yaml file you can specify commands by:

```
container_commands:
  01_client:
    command: "cd ./server && npm install && npm run build"
    leader_only: true
  02_server:
    command: "cd ./client && npm install && npm run build"
    leader_only: true
```

Elastic Beanstalk will execute those commands when you run `eb  deploy` automatically.

For more information see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Comment: This is helpful, thanks, though I think these are YAML files rather than JSON.